# Как записать данные в переменную javascript через ajax запрос с использованием json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

У меня есть массив в файле getcoords.php, который я кодирую в формат json и передаю в index.php, вот код:

```
<?php
function getResults() {
$db=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', "");
mysqli_select_db($db,'test1');
$result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `forchart` WHERE `id_series`=1 ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
return $row;
}
$coords=getResults();
echo json_encode($coords);
?>
```

Далее я получаю этот массив, декодирую и вывожу внутри ajax. (код ниже).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
url: 'load_from_bd/getcoords.php',
success: function(coords_){
coords = JSON.parse(coords_);
alert(coords_); // просто вывод ответа
alert(coords.x4); // распарсим JSON
},
error: function(request) {
console.log("ERROR", request);
}
});
});
alert(coords.x4);
</script>
```

А мне нужно вывести этот массив в переменную и работать с ним дальше. Если я пытаюсь потом обращаться к полученной переменной coords, то запрос мне выводит, что она не определена, т к судя по всему, она "умирает" внутри ajax запроса. Внутри же запроса alert работает корректно. Как мне вынести её "наружу" запроса? Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: объявите ее на вехнем уровне до запроса

Comment: Ну так в success-колбеке и работай.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что область видимости переменной coords это callback-функция.
Чтобы использовать переменную в глобальной области видимости - нужно ее объявить, а потом изменить

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let coords; //инициализация переменной

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'load_from_bd/getcoords.php',
        success: function (coords_) {
            coords = JSON.parse(coords_); //задаем значение переменной
            alert(coords_); // просто вывод ответа
            alert(coords.x4); // распарсим JSON
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log("ERROR", request);
        }
    });

    alert(coords.x4); // используем глобальную переменную
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Только с одним важным уточнением! В ajax запросе надо добавить `async: false,` Без этого работать не будет!